# Custom HTML elements not rendering children

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

The following code does not render the CategoryElement's children - only the <p> element within the Shadow Root. How do I make the CategoryElement's children render?

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            class CategoryElement extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();
                    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
                    this.header = document.createElement('p');
                    this.header.innerText = 'Shadow Header';
                    this.shadowRoot.append(this.header);
                }
            }
            customElements.define('category-element', CategoryElement);

            var elem = document.createElement('category-element');
            document.body.appendChild(elem);

            var outer = document.createElement('p');
            outer.innerText = 'Outer Header';
            elem.appendChild(outer);
        </script>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this gets you there, but I'm no shadow dom expert by any stretch of the imagination.

I added `.shadowRoot` as shown here:

```
elem.shadowRoot.appendChild(outer);
```

When I inspect with the dev tools I can see that both `<p>` are in side the shadow-root element (if that's the correct way to refer to it).

```html
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    class CategoryElement extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({
          mode: 'open'
        });
        this.header = document.createElement('p');
        this.header.innerText = 'Shadow Header';
        this.shadowRoot.append(this.header);
      }
    }
    customElements.define('category-element', CategoryElement);

    var elem = document.createElement('category-element');
    document.body.appendChild(elem);

    var outer = document.createElement('p');
    outer.innerText = 'Outer Header';
    elem.shadowRoot.appendChild(outer);
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't what I was asking for. I want child elements, not a shadow dom, as they are more annoying to manipulate and style.

Comment: If you do not want shadowDOM, then do not attach one with: ``this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});``

Comment: Or [learn to use ``<slot>`` element(s)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot) to display lightDOM content in a shadowDOM ``<slot>``